# java in method signature generics extends from this

Tags: java, generics, extends

This does not work because of `this.class` it must be `Tower`, but I want that all classes that extends from `Tower` are assignable from the current `Tower` like `ArrowTower` or something else.

```
public Tower upgrade(Class<? extends this.class> c) {
    try {
        return c.getConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I can check it so, but I want that the complier says you thats the wrong extends hierarchy or something else

```
if (!this.getClass().isAssignableFrom(c))
{
    return null;
}
```

I want it so because there are an `ArrowTower` and a `FireArrowTower` that are extends from `ArrowTower` and there are a `CannonTower` and a `FireCannonTower` that are extends from `CannonTower`. But if want to upgrade an `ArrowTower` its possible to upgrade it to an `CannonTower`, but this should not be allowed.

See:

```
    Tower t1 = new ArrowTower();
    t1 = t1.upgrade(FireArrowTower.class);

    Tower t2 = new CannonTower();
    t2 = t2.upgrade(Tower.class); // Here it musst be an Error
```

Sorry for my bad english I'm from Germany :D

Comment: No need to bash germans, even your english is good :)

Comment: Why not `upgrade(Class<? extends Tower> c)`? Any class extending `Tower` would be accepted. Isn't it what you're looking for?

Comment: *Side note:* if German people feel bad for their English, then I should feel reaaaaaally bad for my people's English (French...).

Comment: because there are an ArrowTower and a FireArrwoTower that are extends from ArrowTower and there are a CannonTower and a FireCannonTower that are extends from CannonTower. But if want to upgrade an ArrowTower its possible to upgrade it to an CannonTower, but this should not be allowed

Comment: So, `upgrade()` is a method in `Tower`, but you want this method to behave differently in subclasses, right? How are you using this method anyway? If you are passing a specific class that you don't get dynamically, then there is probably no point in dealing with generics, you could just have separate methods.

Comment: You should probably update your post to reflect what you have said in the comments

Comment: its because of redundancy

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible due to the principle that, loosely speaking, a subclass should support everything the superclass supports (see also the [Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) substitution principle).

Let me illustrate. With the structure you describe, you want the compiler to accept:

```
Tower myTower = new Tower();
myTower.upgrade(ArrowTower.class)
```

.. but not:

```
GunTower myTower = new GunTower();
myTower.upgrade(ArrowTower.class);
```

right? That would cause trouble, though. Look:

```
Tower myTower = new GunTower();
myTower.upgrade(ArrowTower.class);
```

Here we only made the type of 'myTower' a bit less specific, and now you'd like the compiler to suddenly disallow this call. That's surprising, and indeed Java doesn't allow it.

Comment: See my changes please, that must be possible